# Прямую речь разрывает авторское предложение, распространённое, - знаки?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

> Неожиданно Дейди выпрямился и указал на землю за моей спиной:
>   «Леопард!» – испуганно воскликнул он и сел на корточки. Я оглянулась в
>   ожидании увидеть свирепую кошку, готовую к прыжку. «Очень маленький»,
>   – добавил Дейди. Я в недоумении покрутила головой из стороны в
>   сторону. «Очень-очень маленький. Большой никогда бы не подошёл так близко к
>   жилищу», – тихо и очень серьёзно сказал мой сафари-бой. Я
>   присмотрелась к каменистой почве, чуть прикрытой нежным бархатом пыли,
>   теперь уже в надежде увидеть очень-очень маленького леопарда, но
>   увидела лишь еле заметный след там, куда указывал проводник. «Давно
>   ушёл. Был здесь около трёх ночи», – сказал Дейди Ноу Лейрана и
>   замолчал.

Так?

Или так:

> Неожиданно Дейди выпрямился и указал на землю за моей спиной:
>   «Леопард! – испуганно воскликнул он и сел на корточки. Я оглянулась в
>   ожидании увидеть свирепую кошку, готовую к прыжку. – Очень маленький,
>   – добавил Дейди. Я в недоумении покрутила головой из стороны в
>   сторону. – Очень-очень маленький. Большой никогда бы не подошёл так близко к
>   жилищу, – тихо и очень серьёзно сказал мой сафари-бой. Я
>   присмотрелась к каменистой почве, чуть прикрытой нежным бархатом пыли,
>   теперь уже в надежде увидеть очень-очень маленького леопарда, но
>   увидела лишь еле заметный след там, куда указывал проводник. – Давно
>   ушёл. Был здесь около трёх ночи», – сказал Дейди Ноу Лейрана и
>   замолчал.

Comment: Прямую речь здесь не разрывает авторское предложение, просто предложения с прямой речью вклиниваются в авторский текст, частая история.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Первый вариант

Первый вариант верен.

#### Второй вариант

Если уж без кавычек, то как реплики, с нового абзаца.

> Неожиданно Дейди выпрямился и указал на землю за моей спиной.
>
> – Леопард! – испуганно воскликнул он и сел на корточки.
>
> Я оглянулась в ожидании увидеть свирепую кошку, готовую к прыжку.
>
> – Очень маленький, – добавил Дейди.
>
> Я в недоумении покрутила головой из стороны в сторону.
>
> – Очень-очень маленький. Большой никогда бы не подошёл так близко к
>   жилищу, – тихо и очень серьёзно сказал мой сафари-бой.
>
> Я присмотрелась к каменистой почве, чуть прикрытой нежным бархатом
>   пыли, теперь уже в надежде увидеть очень-очень маленького леопарда, но
>   увидела лишь еле заметный след там, куда указывал проводник.
>
> – Давно ушёл. Был здесь около трёх ночи, – сказал Дейди Ноу Лейрана
>   и замолчал.

Comment: Людмила, если слова автора разрывают прямую речь, то кавычки ставятся в начале и в конце прямой речи. Значит, первый вариант не может быть верным.

Comment: Где ж Вы здесь видите одну прямую речь? Просто предложения с прямой речью вклиниваются в авторский текст. Это название вопроса неверно, а пунктуация верная.

Answer (score 2):

При оформлении **диалога в строку** каждая реплика берётся **в кавычки**. Между репликами **ставится тире**, если встречается прямая речь разных авторов; в противном случае **тире не ставится.**

Неожиданно Дейди выпрямился и указал на землю за моей спиной. "Леопард!" – испуганно воскликнул он и сел на корточки. Я оглянулась в ожидании увидеть свирепую кошку, готовую к прыжку. "Очень маленький", – добавил Дейди. Я в недоумении покрутила головой из стороны в сторону. "Очень-очень маленький. Большой никогда бы не подошёл так близко к жилищу", – тихо и очень серьёзно сказал мой сафари-бой. Я присмотрелась к каменистой почве, чуть прикрытой нежным бархатом пыли, теперь уже в надежде увидеть очень-очень маленького леопарда, но увидела лишь еле заметный след там, куда указывал проводник.  "Давно ушёл. Был здесь около трёх ночи», – сказал Дейди Ноу Лейрана и замолчал.

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, это первый вариант из вопроса, или есть отличия?

Comment: Двоеточия нет в начале. Я бы не стала здесь использовать оформление текста в абзац, так как авторское описание занимает центральное место, а реплики Дейди как бы сопровождают его. Фактически это же   не диалог, говорит только Дейди.